# How to show number of patches in a neighbourhood?

Tags: raster, shapefile

Given one raster file containing only one zone that indicates patches of vegetation in a city and a shapefile containing neighbourhoods for the city, explain how you could create a map that shows the number of patches in each neighbourhood.

Do you use topology?

Comment: _Shows_ the number, _counts_ the number, _shows_ the patches? Can you be more specific about the goal result?

Comment: shows the number of patches in each neighbourhood

Comment: How would you do this in Arcmap?
Would you convert the shape file to a raster?

Comment: Please take care to always specify the GIS software and version that you are using as part of your question body.  That way people do not spend time writing answers involving software that you are not using while their time is taken from a question for which that software is a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in QGIS using the [Zonal Statistics](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html) tool:

> you can analyze the results of a thematic classification. It allows to
>   calculate several values of the pixels of a raster layer with the help
>   of a polygonal vector layer (see figure_zonal_statistics). You can
>   calculate the sum, the mean value and the total count of the pixels
>   that are within a polygon. The plugin generates output columns in the
>   vector layer with a user-defined prefix.

[image]

Comment: How would you do this in Arcmap? Would you convert the shape file to a raster?

Comment: In ArcMap, you can use [Zonal Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000w7000000) or [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics_as_Table/009z000000w8000000/) (assuming you have Spatial Analyst extension). The shapefile of neighborhoods is the zone, the raster of vegetation is the value input.

Comment: How would I proceed if my end goal is to show the number of patches in each neighbourhood?

Would I then use region group on the neighbourhood zone layer? 
Then use cell statistics (sum) to find the total number of patches in each?